# Javascript element object not referencing DOM Input element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating an HTML input element in JS, then inserting it into the DOM. However, after it is inserted, the JS element object does not reference the new DOM element.

The element type button element and input type 'submit' work too, but the input element seems to not work with either 'number' or 'text,' which I would be using.

```
let parent = document.createElement('div');
let child = document.createElement('div');
let childInput = document.createElement('input');
childInput.type = 'text';
childInput.value = 'foobar';

child.append(childInput);
parent.append(child);
document.body.append(parent);
```

There are no errors, however in chrome dev tools I can see the JS element object is not tied to the DOM object for the input when type is set to text or number. The element IS inserted into the DOM, however it does not reflect the JS object reference, and the value is not inserted into the DOM element, nor would the class, id, etc.

Edit: Also, it does not work when using the appendChild function either.

Comment: please share your HTML as well, this would help people trying to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to change the HTML attributes by setting the JavaScript properties, which doesn't always work. You can use `myElement.setAttribute(attributeName, newValue)` to change the HTML attributes using JavaScript (and `myElement.propertyName = newValue` to change the JavaScript properties.)

Note that the initial value of the `value` attribute is reflected in the `defaultValue` property. (There are a few other oddball property names like this where reserved words in JS conflict with HTML terms.)

Note also that HTML attributes are case-insensitive, whereas JS properties are case-sensitive -- and `kebab-case` attributes get mapped to `camelCase` properties.

Much more info on this can be found here: https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties

```js
let parent = document.createElement('div');
let child = document.createElement('div');
let childInput = document.createElement('input');
childInput.type = 'text';
childInput.id = 'initialId';
childInput.classList.add('someClass');
childInput.defaultValue = 'initial value';
child.append(childInput);
parent.append(child);
document.body.append(parent);

// Initial attributes
let insertedChild = document.getElementById('initialId');
console.log(insertedChild.outerHTML);

// Modified attributes
insertedChild.setAttribute('id', 'changedId');
console.log("`id` property (reflected from attribute): " + insertedChild.id);
insertedChild.setAttribute('value', 'changedValue');
console.log("`value` property (reflected from attribute): " + insertedChild.value);
console.log(insertedChild.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very informative. Is it also possible to add event listeners this way

Comment: To add an event listener to any element, you can just use this kind of pattern: `myElement.addEventListener("click", myFunction); function myFunction(event){ let clickedElement = event.target; console.log(clickedElement.id); }`. This doesn't really depend on whether you've set any particular attribute or property (except of course, in this example, the `id` property being logged.) If you need to become more familiar with this process, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener.

Comment: I am familiar with the event listeners, they weren't working before using the IDs. I realized that yes, I just must resort to having the elements populate the DOM first, then call them with the getElementById or querySelector. I have since moved past the problem, thanks again for the insight with the setAttribute property

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense because event listeners are listening in the DOM (or sometimes a shadowDOM, I guess), so you can't add one to an element until the element exists in the DOM. If you want to add the event listener first, you can add it to a parent (or other ancestor) element, then use an `if` statement inside your listener to respond appropriately depending on which element was the `event.target`. (This works because your listener code can check for the existence of your dynamically created elements each time it runs instead of needing them to exist beforehand.)